# Monotouch Objective C API Binding

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

I am currently working on a MonoTouch project and needed to add in an Objective C API for use with a card reader. I am having some difficulty understanding the basics of getting the binding working after reading all of the documents provided by Xamarin. I am trying to code for an interface and I am getting mixed messages regarding how to code the C# versions of the methods. I've seen ways of doing it where you actually call the Objective C Runtime using handles and all that jazz, like so:

```
    [Export("doSomething")]
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        return Runtime.GetNSObject(
            Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend(this.Handle, selNextObject.Handle));
    }
    // I know this code doesn't match what you would do in a void method
    // but bear with me
```

but I've also seen examples creating method definitions as simple as

```
    //from obj-c code -(void) doSomething;
    [Export("doSomething")]
    void DoSomething();
```

Does the method automatically recognize the 'doSomething' method in the Objective C API and carry out those operations or do I have to code the C# method operations myself somehow? (I am aware of Selectors, but I am not very familiar with them or what they do/how to properly use them) I would appreciate any help or explanations possible. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the binding generator, it does all the work for you.   This is what we use for almost every bit of API in MonoTouch.

But if you want to roll things out by hand, you manually call msgSend

Comment: So what work does the developer have to do? Do I still have to create a binding project or is there an easier way to do this whole thing? Sorry, I'm kind of confused. Thank you so much for your willingness to help!

Comment: Yes, you do have to create the binding project.   The binding project is what provides the binding and does the magic for you.  If you do not do that, then you have to go down the manual route which is a world of pain.